# Ext.Net button change font size

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, extjs, ext.net

how I can change font size of a Ext.Net button.
I have tryed:
Css:

```
.x-16
{
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Razor:

```
X.Button().Icon(Icon.PluginAdd).ID("NewTask").Text("New Task").Handler("Myapp.ShowWinAddTask").Cls("x-16")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the CSS declaration to this

```
.x-16 .x-btn-default-small .x-btn-inner
{
    font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

and set the CtCls property to your custom class

```
X.Button().CtCls="x-16"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a bit different solution.

It prunes "-small" from the CSS rule. That "-small" part depends on a Button's Scale.

Also it prunes the "!important" statement which is good to avoid as much as possible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ext.Net.MVC v2 Example</title>    

    <style>
        .x-16 .x-btn-inner {
            font-size: 16px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    @Html.X().ResourceManager()

    @Html.X().Button().Text("Button").Cls("x-16")
</body>
</html>
```